# Using a Singleton for Realm in UI-Thread

Tags: android, realm

I use Realm in a Project. I built this RealmActivity to easily use Realm in code with getActivity.getRealm().

```
public abstract class RealmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (!realm.isClosed()) {
        realm.close();
    }
}


public Realm getRealm() {
    return realm;
}
```

Now I want to delete the Realm-file to clear the data for this session/user. To do this, all RealmInstances have to be closed. I tried to start a Logout-Activity with an intent to clear the activityStack. It works fine for my Nexus 5 (Android 6) but not for my Nexus 4 (Android 5).

My idea was to create a Singleton for the RealmInstance, which used in the UI-Thread

```
public abstract class RealmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    realm = ManagerLayer.getInstance().getRealm();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


public Realm getRealm() {
    return realm;
}
```

}

Now, I got only one Instance and can close it before deleting the file. But I never close the RealmInstance when I´m not logging out. Is that an Problem?

But when I clear the ActivityStack and the onDestroy() method isn´t called, the RealmInstance for the Activity gets never closed, too. Right?

Can I use a Singleton for the UI-Thread realmInstance? I never pass it to another Thread and never close it.
Or is there another solution to close all RealmInstances to delete the RealmFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the instance of some object that is needed for the whole application, you should keep this instance in:

1. The `Application` class, extending it and setting the `android:name` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Another class that is not an Android component, a simple java class.

Talking about lifecycles, if you have some action that closes the Realm instance and this is enough, simply create a clear method in your singleton and call it properly.

If this is not the case, you have to keep in mind that you can never warranty that the `onDestroy` method is called, but if you don't release the resources because the process has been killed, you don't have to worry at all, since when a process is killed all the objects not persisted will be completely released, even if they are using the filesystem or the network.

Comment: Using application class is how I did it as well and providing a public static instance to it. But remember that this instance only works in the UI thread, for new threads you need to get a new instance.

Comment: I would also check the getInstance use using `Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()`